# Get time left of session, Yii / PHP

Tags: php, yii

I want to create a controller in Yii that returns how many seconds the users session got left. Every time the user does something on my page, the timout is being reset which it should. But my problem is two things.

1. How can i get how long a session has got left?
2. How to create a controller in Yii that doesn't reset the session timeout.

Comment: With `Yii::app()->getSession()->getTimeout()` you can get the length of the current session. This doesn't reset by default.

Comment: That always returns 1440, i am interested in knowing for how much longer the session is valid.

Comment: Take a look at the code in http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/timeout-dialog/ . This extension basically displays a modal window X seconds before the session expires. It may do exactly what you are trying to achieve, or at least offer you some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `allowAutoLogin` as true, you have to specify a duration for the user session as a second argument to `login()` function. In that case you have store the timestamp of login time and calculate the differnce.

If `allowAutoLogin` is false, you have to get the session timeout by `ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime')` and then store it and show the user the difference.